# Storing segmented control value as variable. How to fix these warnings?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code but I am getting warning "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to `NSInteger` *(aka int*) from int. The `qAVariable` is an int variable and I am only trying to store whatever value is selected as that variable. Would this work despite the warnings?

```
- (IBAction)segmentcontrollerA {

    if (controlA.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        qAVariable = 0;
    }
    if (controlA.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        qAVariable = 1;
    }
    if (controlA.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        qAVariable = 2;
    }
    if (controlA.selectedSegmentIndex == 3) {
        qAVariable = 3;
    }
    if (controlA.selectedSegmentIndex == 4) {
        qAVariable = 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: In which line is the warning appearing?

Comment: Code would look alot cleaner if you used a switch statement!

Comment: So the warnings are appearing on the 2nd-5th if statements. The first one with value 0 isn't displaying any warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning an integer value to `qAVariable`. Your warning suggests that you didn't declare this as flat integeral datatype, but as a pointer, i.e. `NSNumber *`, or `int *`.

Comment: I declared it as NSInteger aka NSInteger *qAVariable; What should it be?

Comment: 'NSInteger' is not 'NSInteger *'. It should be 'NSInteger', which typically is just a typedef to 'int'. 'NInteger *' is a pointer to an 'NSInteger', something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

NSinteger is a 32bit int (so your basic `int`) when compiling in 32bit architectures, while it's a 64bit integer (a `long`) when compiling for the new 64bit arch. That explains the warning. You can simply cast you NSInteger to int to avoid the warning:

```
qAVariable = (int)controlA.selectedSegmentIndex;
```

Comment: His code doesn't use this, and an integer would not issue a "int to pointer conversion" warning.

Comment: If I understand correctly he was trying to assign directly the selectedSegmentIndex (as reason would dictate) to his var, and to avoid the warning he switched to that bunch of if statements. No reason to do that.

Comment: No, his code doens't do this, and even if it did, it wouldn't cause this error. In fact, this casting wouldn't change anything, as selectedSegmentIndex is an NSInteger, which could raise a signed/unsigned warning at best.

Comment: He does mention this warning: "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion".

Answer (score 0):

You can also change your property to this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger qAVariable;
```